FLS Create issue for Lead convert
In my managed package we are converting a lead using apex.
    List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(listOfLeadConvert);

Checkmarx is throwing a FLS create error. I know i can use  as user for the normal sobject inserts.
 insert as user acc;

How can i remove the checkmarx error for Database.Leadconvert ? Or do we need to log it as a false positive?
Similarly how do we handle the same FLS create error for Database.Insert()

You could use Database.convertLead(leadsToConvert, allOrNone, accessLevel), that lets you set the desired AccessLevel, USER_MODE in your case:
List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(listOfLeadConvert, true, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);

This should remove the Checkmarx error.
The same goes for Database.insert(records, accessLevel);

Unfortunately checkmarx still does report it even after adding the AccessLevel. Maybe its something which might have to flagged as false positive
